# Implementation of a given mathematical model into CPLEX

Tags: modeling, cplex, opl

At university i was given a paper about inventory management. The task is now to implement a part of the model into IBM CPLEX and i would therefore need some help.

Comment: Please refine your question to explain what you tried, and why it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is it possible to write you a private mail or message? :)

Comment: it is about the implementation of the model of honhon et al. Assortment planning and inventory decisions under stock-out based substitution

Answer (score 2):

The CPLEX documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_home.html has a good number of tutorials and examples. To get started with CPLEX it is a good idea to look at these and the many examples that ship with CPLEX. There are some examples for inventory problems.

Comment: it is about the implementation of the model of honhon et al. Assortment planning and inventory decisions under stock-out based substitution∗

Comment: Usually you can translate a mathematical model more or less 1:1 to OPL. OPL is the modeling language included in CPLEX Optimization Studio. So once you got familiar with OPL (via the links I posted) you stand a very good chance to translate the formulations in the paper to OPL.